# Error when trying to save array using NSUserDefaults()

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to save an array using `NSUserDefaults()` so that I can access the data even after closing the program. I Have always managed to use it successfully in the past saving Ints and Strings. However when I try to save an array it doesn't work. Here is an example:

```
 var superarray = [AnyObject?]()
    superarray.append("Test")
    superarray.append(3)
    superarray.append(NSDate()) //random examples

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(superarray, forKey: "AnyKey")
```

It gives the error: "Cannot convert value of type '[AnyObject?]' to expected argument type 'AnyObject?' "

Does this mean that `.setObject()` cannot take arrays? Is there another alternative?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSUserDefaults can only store object with property list type.

Reminder, plist are limited to these objects:

- NSData
- NSString
- NSNumber
- NSDate
- NSArray
- NSDictionary

Se here you could use NSMutableArray instead of your mutable Array

```
let superarray = NSMutableArray();
superarray.addObject("Test")
superarray.addObject(3)
superarray.addObject(NSDate())

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(superarray, forKey: "AnyKey")
```

More details here:
http://www.codingexplorer.com/nsuserdefaults-a-swift-introduction/